# C# dictionary - one key, many values

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, datasource

I want to create a data store to allow me to store some data.

The first idea was to create a dictionary where you have one key with many values, so a bit like a one-to-many relationship.

I think the dictionary only has one key value.

How else could I store this information?

Answer (score 74):

As of .NET 3.5+, instead of using a `Dictionary<IKey, List<IValue>>`, you can use a `Lookup` from the LINQ namespace:

```
// Lookup Order by payment status (1:m)
// would need something like Dictionary<Boolean, IEnumerable<Order>> orderIdByIsPayed
ILookup<Boolean, Order> byPayment = orderList.ToLookup(o => o.IsPayed);
IEnumerable<Order> payedOrders = byPayment[false];
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx):

> A Lookup<TKey, TElement> resembles a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>. The
> difference is that a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> maps keys to single
> values, whereas a Lookup<TKey, TElement> maps keys to collections of
> values.
>
> You can create an instance of a Lookup<TKey, TElement> by calling
> ToLookup on an object that implements IEnumerable.

You may also want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403499/303290) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1403493/303290). For more information, consult [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx).

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqLookupSpike
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // Init
            var orderList = new List<Order>();
            orderList.Add(new Order(1, 1, 2010, true)); // (orderId, customerId, year, isPayed)
            orderList.Add(new Order(2, 2, 2010, true));
            orderList.Add(new Order(3, 1, 2010, true));
            orderList.Add(new Order(4, 2, 2011, true));
            orderList.Add(new Order(5, 2, 2011, false));
            orderList.Add(new Order(6, 1, 2011, true));
            orderList.Add(new Order(7, 3, 2012, false));

            // Lookup Order by its id (1:1, so usual dictionary is ok)
            Dictionary<Int32, Order> orders = orderList.ToDictionary(o => o.OrderId, o => o);

            // Lookup Order by customer (1:n)
            // would need something like Dictionary<Int32, IEnumerable<Order>> orderIdByCustomer
            ILookup<Int32, Order> byCustomerId = orderList.ToLookup(o => o.CustomerId);
            foreach (var customerOrders in byCustomerId)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} ordered:", customerOrders.Key);
                foreach (var order in customerOrders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("    Order {0} is payed: {1}", order.OrderId, order.IsPayed);
                }
            }

            // The same using old fashioned Dictionary
            Dictionary<Int32, List<Order>> orderIdByCustomer;
            orderIdByCustomer = byCustomerId.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
            foreach (var customerOrders in orderIdByCustomer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} ordered:", customerOrders.Key);
                foreach (var order in customerOrders.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("    Order {0} is payed: {1}", order.OrderId, order.IsPayed);
                }
            }

            // Lookup Order by payment status (1:m)
            // would need something like Dictionary<Boolean, IEnumerable<Order>> orderIdByIsPayed
            ILookup<Boolean, Order> byPayment = orderList.ToLookup(o => o.IsPayed);
            IEnumerable<Order> payedOrders = byPayment[false];
            foreach (var payedOrder in payedOrders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Order {0} from Customer {1} is not payed.", payedOrder.OrderId, payedOrder.CustomerId);
            }
        }

        class Order
        {
            // Key properties
            public Int32 OrderId { get; private set; }
            public Int32 CustomerId { get; private set; }
            public Int32 Year { get; private set; }
            public Boolean IsPayed { get; private set; }

            // Additional properties
            // private List<OrderItem> _items;

            public Order(Int32 orderId, Int32 customerId, Int32 year, Boolean isPayed)
            {
                OrderId = orderId;
                CustomerId = customerId;
                Year = year;
                IsPayed = isPayed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Remark on Immutability**

By default, *lookups* are kind of immutable and accessing the `internal`s would involve reflection.
If you need mutability and don't want to write your own wrapper, you could use [`MultiValueDictionary`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Generic.MultiValueDictionary/System/Collections/Generic/MultiValueDictionary.cs) (formerly known as [`MultiDictionary`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/)) from [corefxlab](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab) (formerly part of[`Microsoft.Experimental.Collections`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections) which isn't updated anymore).

Comment: Suppose key and values are both of type string then why not `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` instead of `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`? List cannot guarantee uniqueness within the value collection for a given key but a set can.

Comment: @user3613932 Not the point of my answer. If you want to enforce uniqueness for values, just `.Distinct()` them before creating the lookup. If you need multisets or keep items ordered or indexed a list seems reasonable.

Comment: @mbx I agree with the correctness and feasibility of your approach. With the list approach, there is an implicit assumption in your answer i.e. the collection of values per key is small, and with this assumption in mind, your answer seems appropriate. However, from a readability perspective, if I use something off the shelf to maintain uniqueness in the collection (set) then I would argue it is more readable as the interfaces/API are clear, and even the class `HashSet` gives a very clear signal to the reader of my code (they don't have to go into my implementation to see what I am doing).

Comment: @user3613932 You mean the first list in the full example, right? This is just boiler plate to show the usage of `ToLookup` and `ILookup` vs the `Dictionary` based implementation.

Answer (score 55):

You can use a list for the second generic type. For example a dictionary of strings keyed by a string:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDict;
```

Answer (score 19):

Microsoft just added an official prelease version of exactly what you're looking for (called a MultiDictionary) available through NuGet here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/

Info on usage and more details can be found through the official MSDN blog post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/06/20/would-you-like-a-multidictionary.aspx

I'm the developer for this package, so let me know either here or on MSDN if you have any questions about performance or anything.

Hope that helps.

**Update**

The `MultiValueDictionary` is now on the [corefxlab repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab), and you can get the NuGet package from [this](https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-corefxlab) MyGet feed.

Comment: Looks like it's now called MultiValueDictionary. I want to use this, but am unsure of its future. The blog hasn't been updated in 3  years. Any ideas as to whether this is safe to use?

Comment: I haven't experimented with the `MultiValueDictionary`, but it implements `IReadOnlyDictionary` which is immutable. Anyway I've updated your answer, looks like that tool moved to the corefxlab repo.

Comment: The second link is broken: *"403 Forbidden"*

Comment: Outdated content ought to be removed (there is a full revision history here) - instead of "Updated" sections. Please [change your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24336576/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 8):

Use this:

```
Dictionary<TKey, Tuple<TValue1, TValue2, TValue3, ...>>
```

Comment: would be handy to know the syntax for adding the values to the dictionary :)

Comment: Oh I see ```something.Add(TKey, new Tuple<int, string>(TValue1, TValue2))```

Answer (score 7):

Your dictionary's value type could be a List, or other class that holds multiple objects.  Something like

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>>
```

for a Dictionary that is keyed by ints and holds a List of strings.

A main consideration in choosing the value type is what you'll be using the Dictionary for. If you'll have to do searching or other operations on the values, then maybe think about using a data structure that helps you do what you want -- like a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1).

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>`.

That would allow each key to reference a **list** of values.

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary of lists (or another type of collection), for example:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IList<int>>();

myDictionary["My key"] = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a very simplistic multi-dictionary, which automates to process of inserting values like this:

```
public class MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>
{
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (TryGetValue(key, out List<TValue> valueList)) {
            valueList.Add(value);
        } else {
            Add(key, new List<TValue> { value });
        }
    }
}
```

This creates an overloaded version of the `Add` method. The original one allows you to insert a list of items for a key, if no entry for this entry exists yet. This version allows you to insert a single item in any case.

You can also base it on a `Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>>` instead, if you don't want to have duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a dictionary with a collection (or any other type/class) as a value. That way you have a single key and you store the values in your collection.

Answer (score 1):

A .NET dictionary does only have a one-to-one relationship for keys and values. But that doesn't mean that a value can't be another array/list/dictionary.

I can't think of a reason to have a one-to-many relationship in a dictionary, but obviously there is one.

If you have different types of data that you want to store to a key, then that sounds like the ideal time to create your own class. Then you have a one-to-one relationship, but you have the value class storing more that one piece of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use;

```
 List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Mappings;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MultiValueDictionary](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/) from Microsoft.

**Example Code:**

```
MultiValueDictionary<string, string> Parameters = new MultiValueDictionary<string, string>();

Parameters.Add("Malik", "Ali");
Parameters.Add("Malik", "Hamza");
Parameters.Add("Malik", "Danish");

//Parameters["Malik"] now contains the values Ali, Hamza, and Danish
```

Comment: Then how do you retrieve those values/elements? without using loops

Comment: This is similar to [Ian Hays's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101069/c-sharp-dictionary-one-key-many-values/24336576#24336576).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to achieve this behavior.

For a more comprehensive solution involving `ILookup<TKey, TElement>`, check out [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824919/75500).

```
public abstract class Lookup<TKey, TElement> : KeyedCollection<TKey, ICollection<TElement>>
{
  protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(ICollection<TElement> item) =>
    item
    .Select(b => GetKeyForItem(b))
    .Distinct()
    .SingleOrDefault();

  protected abstract TKey GetKeyForItem(TElement item);

  public void Add(TElement item)
  {
    var key = GetKeyForItem(item);
    if (Dictionary != null && Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var collection))
      collection.Add(item);
    else
      Add(new List<TElement> { item });
  }

  public void Remove(TElement item)
  {
    var key = GetKeyForItem(item);
    if (Dictionary != null && Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var collection))
    {
      collection.Remove(item);
      if (collection.Count == 0)
        Remove(key);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Item
{
  public string Key { get; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public Item(string key, string value = null) { Key = key; Value = value; }
}

public class Lookup : Lookup<string, Item>
{
  protected override string GetKeyForItem(Item item) => item.Key;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var toRem = new Item("1", "different");
  var single = new Item("2", "single");
  var lookup = new Lookup()
  {
    new Item("1", "hello"),
    new Item("1", "hello2"),
    new Item(""),
    new Item("", "helloo"),
    toRem,
    single
  };

  lookup.Remove(toRem);
  lookup.Remove(single);
}
```

Note: the key must be immutable (or remove and re-add upon key-change).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an dictionary with `<T,T[]>` type,
(when T = any type you want)
When you initialize the values of dictionary items, declare an array each key.

For Example:

```
 `Dictionary<int, string[]> dictionaty  = new Dictionary<int, string[]>() {
                {1, new string[]{"a","b","c"} },
                {2, new string[]{"222","str"} }
            }; `
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61076777/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to have a `Dictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TValue>`, where 2 keys are needed to access a certain item. Solutions using `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` will create as many lists as there are unique values for TKey, which takes a lot of memory and slows down the performance. The other problem when having only 1 key is that it becomes difficult to remove one particular item.

Since I couldn't find such a class, I wrote one myself:

```
  public class SortedBucketCollectionClass<TKey1, TKey2, TValue>:
    IEnumerable<TValue>, ICollection<TValue>, 
    IReadOnlySortedBucketCollection<TKey1, TKey2, TValue>
    where TKey1 : notnull, IComparable<TKey1>
    where TKey2 : notnull, IComparable<TKey2>
    where TValue : class {...}
```

It supports access with only TKey1, which returns an enumerator over all items having TKey1 and access with TKey1, TKEy2, which returns a particular item. There are also enumerators over all stored items and one that enumerates all items with a certain range of TKey. This is convenient, when TKey1 is DateTime and one wants all items from a certain week, month or year.

I wrote a detailed article on CodeProject with code samples:
[SortedBucketCollection: A memory efficient SortedList accepting multiple items with the same key](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5317083/SortedBucketCollection-A-memory-efficient-SortedLi)

You can get the source code on CodeProject or Github:
[StorageLib/StorageLib/SortedBucketCollection.cs](https://github.com/PeterHuberSg/StorageLib/blob/master/StorageLib/SortedBucketCollection.cs)