# Multi Value Dictionary?

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

Anyone know of a good implementation of a `MultiValueDictionary`? Basically, I want something that allows multiple values per key. I want to be able to do something like

```
dict.Add(key, val);
```

And if the key doesn't already exist, it will add it, if it does, it will just add another value to that key. I'm just going to iterate over it, so I don't really care about the other retrieval methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dictionary-one-key-many-values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101069/c-sharp-dictionary-one-key-many-values?lq=1)

Comment: Take a look at the LookUp class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't exist, but you can build one pretty quickly from Dictionary and List:

```
class MultiDict<TKey, TValue>  // no (collection) base class
{
   private Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> _data =  new Dictionary<TKey,List<TValue>>();

   public void Add(TKey k, TValue v)
   {
      // can be a optimized a little with TryGetValue, this is for clarity
      if (_data.ContainsKey(k))
         _data[k].Add(v);
      else
        _data.Add(k, new List<TValue>() { v}) ;
   }

   // more members
}
```

Comment: Lists don't have very efficient inserts, do they? Don't they use an array internally?

Comment: Yes they use an array, and sometimes a List.Add() will need to re-allocate. But mostly Add is O(1).

Comment: @Mark: `List<T>.Add` has [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized) O(1) performance, and is generally *faster* than `LinkedList<T>.AddLast` because it requires fewer operations. `LinkedList<T>.AddLast` might make sense if you want to *never* have an O(n) resize happen (even though it will happen rarely on a `List<T>` that you're only adding to).

Comment: @Dan: Ah.. so you're saying the "constant" times in the LinkedList generally outweigh the performance of a List?

Comment: @Mark: Yes. I've seldom seen cases where it made sense to choose a `LinkedList<T>` over a `List<T>` when you're never inserting/removing from the middle (that's where `LinkedList<T>` really shines). When you're just adding to the *end*, `LinkedList<T>` is just costing you a lot more (e.g., creation of `LinkedListNode<T>` objects => more fields to initialize => elimination of arrays' performance advantage due to extremely optimized memory access) for very little benefit: one `LinkedList<T>.AddLast` in a blue moon will outperform a single `List<T>.Add`. The rest will be the opposite.

Comment: @Dan: Good to know. I'll stop using LinkedList then :)

Comment: List is also more cache friendly compared to linked list

Answer (score 46):

Microsoft just added an official prelease version of exactly what you're looking for (called a `MultiValueDictionary`) available through NuGet here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/

Info on usage and more details can be found through the official MSDN blog post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/06/20/would-you-like-a-multidictionary.aspx

I'm the developer for this package, so let me know either here or on MSDN if you have any questions about performance or anything.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This answer needs to rise up.

Comment: Is there a typo in your 2nd snippet? `myDictionary.Add(2)` -- don't you need to specify a key?

Comment: @Mark you are correct, there was an error in the second example, but it has since been fixed. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: It has been renamed to 'MultiValueDictionary'.

Comment: @JasonBoyd Hah. That's fabulous. I called it 5 years ago.

Comment: @IanHays link to blog returns 403

Comment: Hi @IanHays! What happened to MultiValueDictionary? I see its code is archived. Was it ever moved to an official home?

Comment: This NuGet is marked deprecated.

Answer (score 25):

You can easily make one from a dictionary of lists:

```
public class MultiValueDictionary<Key, Value> : Dictionary<Key, List<Value>> {

  public void Add(Key key, Value value) {
    List<Value> values;
    if (!this.TryGetValue(key, out values)) {
      values = new List<Value>();
      this.Add(key, values);
    }
    values.Add(value);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) for your second generic parameter:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,int,object>>();
dict.Add("key", new Tuple<string,int,object>("string1", 4, new Object()));
```

Or even , a generic List as a second generic parameter:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,List<myType>>();
```

That will allow you to bind multiple values to a single key.

For ease of use, you can create an extension method that will check for existence of a key and addition to the list.

Comment: Yeah, but then I have to check if the key exists before adding to it every time. I want the collection class to handle that automatically.

Comment: You can inherit from Dictionary, overriding `add` to do this check. It is not resource intensive, as checking for a key is pretty quick. Don't optimize before you _need_ to.

Comment: No one said anything about optimization, this is just about convenience. And if I inherit from dictionary, I'm pretty sure I would have to `new` the `Add` method, not `override` which I generally don't like to do because it breaks inheritance. Also, the method signatures need to be slightly different, because some them should actually return lists of TValues, rather than just a TValue. Lastly, I'm not really sure why you've suggested a Tuple.. those aren't expandable?

Comment: @Mark - You say "multiple values for key". It wasn't clear that the values need to be expandable. See my update, regarding the second generic type being a `List`.

Comment: @Oded: That's why I wrote the paragraph below ;) "it will just add another value to that key" re: update: An extension method is a clever solution... I wanted the enumerator to return KeyValuePairs though, not Key,List<Value> pairs though.

Comment: @Mark - you can always use a `Dictionary` as your generic parameter, instead of a `List` (`Dictionary<string,Dictionary<key,value>>`), as a Dictionary is in essence a set of KVPs.

Comment: @Mark - I've seen `List<List<List<>>>` in the past... Not pretty, but did the job.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one I wrote a while back that you can use.

It has a "MultiValueDictionary" class that inherits from Dictionary.

It also has an extension class that allows you to use the special Add functionality on any Dictionary where the value type is an IList; that way you're not forced to use the custom class if you don't want to.

```
public class MultiValueDictionary<KeyType, ValueType> : Dictionary<KeyType, List<ValueType>>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Hide the regular Dictionary Add method
    /// </summary>
    new private void Add(KeyType key, List<ValueType> value)
    {            
        base.Add(key, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified value to the multi value dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the element to add.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the element to add. The value can be null for reference types.</param>
    public void Add(KeyType key, ValueType value)
    {
        //add the value to the dictionary under the key
        MultiValueDictionaryExtensions.Add(this, key, value);
    }
}

public static class MultiValueDictionaryExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified value to the multi value dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the element to add.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the element to add. The value can be null for reference types.</param>
    public static void Add<KeyType, ListType, ValueType>(this Dictionary<KeyType, ListType> thisDictionary, 
                                                         KeyType key, ValueType value)
    where ListType : IList<ValueType>, new()
    {
        //if the dictionary doesn't contain the key, make a new list under the key
        if (!thisDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            thisDictionary.Add(key, new ListType());
        }

        //add the value to the list at the key index
        thisDictionary[key].Add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course... inherit from a dict with a list instead! Clever. What's that `new()` bit do? Don't think I've seen that before.

Comment: Taken from MSDN; Use the new modifier to explicitly hide a member inherited from a base class. To hide an inherited member, declare it in the derived class using the same name, and modify it with the new modifier.

Comment: @DoctaJonez - I believe is he asking about the generic parameter constraint (the only `new()` in the code). @Mark - it is a [generic parameter constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) requiring the passed in generic type to have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: @DoctaJonez: I think @Mark means your `where ListType : new()` constraint. (@Mark: That means `ListType` must have a public parameterless constructor. Also, I'm surprised you would like this answer which hides the `base.Add` method as it seems you disliked that very aspect of Oded's answer.)

Comment: @Dan: Yes.. I noticed my hypocritcalness too. I still don't love it, but at least in this case he made it private and added a 2nd method with a different signature... which still doesn't fix the inheritance problem, but... I dunno! I'm trying to find the lesser of evils. @Oded: Yes, that's what I was referring too. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark: Go with Henk's answer. It isn't evil at all ;)

Comment: This is way, way late, but you could remove the `where ListType: new()` constraint by having a `Func<ListType>` parameter. Then instead of doing `thisDictionary.Add(key, new ListType());`, you could do `thisDictionary.Add(key, func());`, and a consumer could do something like `() => new MyCustomList(args)`. Then you wouldn't have to inherit from `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>`-- you could inherit from `Dictionary<TKey, IList<TValue>>`

Comment: the only problem I have with this is that if somehow you pass this as IDictionary<K, T> Add(key, value) will call the base - to successfully make this work you'll have to create a trully overridable dictionary just like the Collection<T> or go through Dictionary base class - I myself have created a OverridableDictionary<K,T> which takes an underlying dictionary and features virtual methods..

Comment: @DemetrisLeptos.  Another way of achieving that would be to explicitly implement the IDictionary interface in the MultiValueDictionary class.  You can then choose which members of the interface you'd like the base class to handle, and which ones you'd like to implement yourself (in this case "Add").

Comment: @DoctorJones yes, my "OverridableDictionary<K,T> implements IDictionary<K, T>" using a wrapped instance - but my focus was on that "public class MultiValueDictionary<KeyType, ValueType> : Dictionary<KeyType, List<ValueType>>" won't allow getting the Add behavior defined there when passed as an interface to e.g. a method (library etc..) using the IDictionary interface which is not aware of the MultiValueDictionary implementation

Answer (score 3):

Just to add my $0.02 to the collection of solutions:

I had the same need back in 2011 and created a `MultiDictionary` with a pedantically complete implementation of all the .NET interfaces. That includes enumerators that return a standard `KeyValuePair<K, T>` and support for the `IDictionary<K, T>.Values` property providing a collection of actual values (instead of an `ICollection<ICollection<T>>`).

That way, it fits in neatly with the rest of the .NET collection classes. I also defined an `IMultiDictionary<K, T>` interface to access operations that are particular to this kind of dictionary:

```
public interface IMultiDictionary<TKey, TValue> :
  IDictionary<TKey, ICollection<TValue>>,
  IDictionary,
  ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>,
  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>,
  IEnumerable {

  /// <summary>Adds a value into the dictionary</summary>
  /// <param name="key">Key the value will be stored under</param>
  /// <param name="value">Value that will be stored under the key</param>
  void Add(TKey key, TValue value);

  /// <summary>Determines the number of values stored under a key</summary>
  /// <param name="key">Key whose values will be counted</param>
  /// <returns>The number of values stored under the specified key</returns>
  int CountValues(TKey key);

  /// <summary>
  ///   Removes the item with the specified key and value from the dictionary
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="key">Key of the item that will be removed</param>
  /// <param name="value">Value of the item that will be removed</param>
  /// <returns>True if the item was found and removed</returns>
  bool Remove(TKey key, TValue value);

  /// <summary>Removes all items of a key from the dictionary</summary>
  /// <param name="key">Key of the items that will be removed</param>
  /// <returns>The number of items that have been removed</returns>
  int RemoveKey(TKey key);

}
```

It can be compiled on anything from .NET 2.0 upwards and so far I've deployed it on the Xbox 360, Windows Phone 7, Linux and Unity 3D. There's also a complete unit test suite covering every single line of the code.

The code is licensed under the [Common Public License](http://opensource.org/licenses/cpl1.0.php) (short: anything goes, but bug fixes to the library's code have to published) and can be found in [my Subversion repository](https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/browser/Nuclex.Support/trunk/Source/Collections).

Comment: Also `IDictionary<TKey, ICollection<TValue>>` implements `IEnumerable` so `IEnumerable` can be removed from the inheritance list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use MultiDictionary class from [PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/).

It returns ICollection{TValue} for the key asked.

Answer (score 1):

Yet [here](https://gist.github.com/weitzhandler/ee19db3b6dc21580d9296f86bfbb1e06)'s my attempt using `ILookup<TKey, TElement>` and an internal `KeyedCollection`. Make sure the key property is immutable.
Cross posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824919/75500).

```
public class Lookup<TKey, TElement> : Collection<TElement>, ILookup<TKey, TElement>
{
  public Lookup(Func<TElement, TKey> keyForItem)
    : base((IList<TElement>)new Collection(keyForItem))
  {
  }

  new Collection Items => (Collection)base.Items;

  public IEnumerable<TElement> this[TKey key] => Items[key];
  public bool Contains(TKey key) => Items.Contains(key);
  IEnumerator<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>.GetEnumerator() => Items.GetEnumerator();

  class Collection : KeyedCollection<TKey, Grouping>
  {
    Func<TElement, TKey> KeyForItem { get; }      
    public Collection(Func<TElement, TKey> keyForItem) => KeyForItem = keyForItem;
    protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(Grouping item) => item.Key;

    public void Add(TElement item)
    {
      var key = KeyForItem(item);
      if (Dictionary != null && Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var collection))
        collection.Add(item);
      else
        Add(new Grouping(key) { item });
    }

    public bool Remove(TElement item)
    {
      var key = KeyForItem(item);
      if (Dictionary != null && Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var collection)
        && collection.Remove(item))
      {
        if (collection.Count == 0)
          Remove(key);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

  }
  class Grouping : Collection<TElement>, IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
  {
    public Grouping(TKey key) => Key = key;
    public TKey Key { get; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do for now...

```
public class MultiValueDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, LinkedList<TValue>> _dict = new Dictionary<TKey, LinkedList<TValue>>();

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if(!_dict.ContainsKey(key)) _dict[key] = new LinkedList<TValue>();
        _dict[key].AddLast(value);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var list in _dict)
            foreach (var value in list.Value)
                yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(list.Key, value);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the (awkward) LinkedList?

Comment: I agree with this and Henk's ideas. Personally I don't like the idea of inheriting from `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` (or similar) as I think it exposes too much (calling code could add/remove from the `List<T>` value directly, for example).

Comment: @Henk: Because I thought it would be more efficient than a `List` (see discussion under your answer). @Dan: Yeah... I was going to implement `IDictionary` instead, but even that.. some of the methods don't make sense.

Comment: Yes, I saw the discussion. I thought as much, the mere presence of LinkedList can be a bit misleading. It is used rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to custom type can be a generic extension that adds key and value when not found:

```
public static V getValue<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> d, K key) where V : new() {
    V v; if (!d.TryGetValue(key, out v)) { v = new V(); d.Add(key, v); } return v; }
```

Sample use:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, LinkedList<int>>();
d.getValue(1).AddLast(2);
```