# Creating a Key/Value List with more than one value per key

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

i need a Key/Value List with more than one Value per Key!

What i have tried:

```
SortedList<string,List<int>> MyList = new SortedList<string,List<int>>();
```

But the Problem is that i cannot add values to the List in the SortedList dynamicly?

```
foreach(var item in MyData)  { MyList.Add(item.Key,item.Value ????); }
```

How can i solve this problem? Is there allready a list with this features?

Regards 
rubiktubik

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi Value Dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850930/multi-value-dictionary)

Comment: Oh Yes, i now use the suggestions for the Multi Value Dictionary Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi value Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569903/multi-value-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement Kirill's valid suggestion of using a Lookup:

```
var lookup = MyData.ToLookup(item => item.Key);
```

and then

```
foreach (var entry in lookup)
{
  string key = entry.Key;
  IEnumerable<int> items = entry;

  foreach (int value in items)
  {
    ...
  }      
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I want to have a List of string as keys and integers as values. I not really understand the usage! How do i create, and add items?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`Lookup(Of TKey, TElement)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class, which

> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the ILookup, you can use a `Dictionary<string,List<int>>`. 
When adding/setting an item you should check if there is a list for that Key or not:

```
Dictionary<string,List<int>> MyList;
void AddItem(string key, int value){
List<int> values;
if(!MyList.TryGet(key, values)){
values= new List<int>();
MyList.Add(key, values);
}
values.Add(value);
}
```

Iterating through the items is:

```
foreach (var entry in MyList)
{
string key = entry.Key;
List<int> values = entry.Value;
}
```

If the values for a key should be unique than instead of a List you can use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).