# Dictionary with multiple values for each key?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

I want the functionality of a Dictionary, but I want to store multiple values for each key. How can this be done in .NET/C#? Is there any built in collection that supports this scenario?

If I do the following:

```
collection.Add("key1", new Order(1));
collection.Add("key1", new Order(2));
collection.Add("key1", new Order(3));
collection.Add("key2", new Order(4));
```

Then running the following should return 3 orders.

```
collection["key1"];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101069/c-sharp-dictionary-one-key-many-values

Comment: If you have already a collection of orders and a key you could use `ToLookup` which returns exactly what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1403499/284240

Comment: Actually, toLookup solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple: Use `Dictionary<string,List<Order>>`

Answer (score 1):

You may use lists for this purpose, if the number of orders per key needs to be variable.

```
collection.Add("key1"), new List<order>(){new Order(1), new Order(2)});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a List, Set, or Dictionary as appropriate for your Value in your Dictionary.

For example, you might do:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should think about this in a different way.  The Dictionary can hold a list of Orders rather than just a single one, like so:

```
var collection = Dictionary<string,List<Order>>();

collection.Add("key1", new List<Order>(new { new Order(1), new Order(2),  new Order(3) });
collection.Add("key2", new Order(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Dictionary<string,order[] order> dict = new Dictionary<string,order[] order>();

    how to access :

    order[] orderArray = dict["key1"];
    order order1 = orderArray[1] ;
    order order2 = orderArray[2] ;

    and goes on...
```