# How to store a value and its list of stings in a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to store a value and its corresponding List of strings in a List. like

```
  Key   Value     
  2      2,3
  2      4,6
  4      3,5,6

 This should be in a list
```

Here i cant use a Dictionary because the same key might repeat. Anyone know how to it kindly help

Comment: how are you going to access Value? By key or by index? (like in DataTables)

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# dictionary one key many values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101069/c-sharp-dictionary-one-key-many-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Lookup`. This is just like a dictionary, only it allows the same key multiple times.

[Here are the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460184.aspx). You have to use the `.ToLookup` extension method on your sequence to create one.

In your case, it seems like you'd need a `ILookup<string, IList<string>>` (or `int` instead of `string`, i don't know your data).

Here's how you can generate the lookup:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> myData = new[] {
    new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>("2", new[] { "2", "3" }),
    new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>("2", new[] { "4", "6" }),
    new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>("4", new[] { "3", "5", "6" }),
};
var myLookup = myData.ToLookup(item => item.Key, item => item.Value.ToList());
```

Comment: But using a Lookup will it not group the first two elements into a single element?

Comment: No, it won't. A lookup has many values for the same keys. So `myLookup[2]` will return a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

How can you distinguish between the two '2' keys? If you do not need to, then what about using a dictionary of lists of lists of int? the key is the key, and the value is a list of lists for all the duplicate keys.

```
Dictionary<int, List<List<int>>> map;
```

Like this

```
var map = new Dictionary<int, List<List<int>>>();

map[2] = new List<List<int>>();
map[2].Add(new List<int>(){ 2, 3});
map[2].Add(new List<int>(){ 4, 6});

map[4] = new List<List<int>>();
map[4].Add(new List<int>(){ 3, 5, 6});

foreach(var key in map.Keys)
{
    foreach(var lists in map[key])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", key);
        foreach(var item in lists)
        {
            Console.Write(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
 }
```

If you do need to distinguish between the keys, then you need to provide a custom hashCode (override the GetHashCode() function) for a custom class or to find other types to be used as a key to guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, just keep it simple and make a class.

```
public class ClassNameHere
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Then use linq for lookups, etc.

```
var someList = new List<ClassNameHere>();
//add some data
var lookupResult = someList.Where(x=>x.Key == 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like (for some reasons) use `Lookup` how it suggest Lucas, and want to use `List` class, you may use following strange construction:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, List<string>>> {
     new Tuple<string, List<string>>("2", new List<string> {"2", "3"})
};
```

But, I think you should think twice before use it. It is better to use `Lookup`, of course.

Comment: If a `Lookup` isn't appropriate, I'd rather go with a `Dictionary<string, IList<string>>` (or something different than `string`)

Comment: It depends. If you only want to save data, and then show it to user, then this variant is simpler.

Comment: Yes, never mind what I just said, I just realized it would actually have to be a `Dictionary<string, IList<IList<string>>>`. Not cool.