# How to join two lists?

Tags: c#, linq

(Full code available at:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/tdKNgH)

I have two lists that are associated by `ParentName` and I would like to join them in a specific way.

```
class Parent
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ChildNames { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}

var parents = new List<Parent>()
{
    new Parent() {ParentName = "Lee"},
    new Parent() {ParentName = "Bob"},
    new Parent() {ParentName = "Tom"}
};

var children = new List<Child>()
{
    new Child() {ParentName = "Lee", ChildName = "A"},
    new Child() {ParentName = "Tom", ChildName = "B"},
    new Child() {ParentName = "Tom", ChildName = "C"}
};
```

I'm using a foreach loop to join, and it works, but **is there a more succinct way to do it?**

```
foreach (var parent in parents)
{
    var p = parent; // to avoid foreach closure side-effects
    p.ChildNames = children.Where(c => c.ParentName == p.ParentName)
                           .Select(c => c.ChildName);
}
```

Here's what the resulting parents list would look like:

```
Parent Children
------ --------
Lee    A 
Bob    (empty) 
Tom    B,C
```

Comment: You may want to consider using a Dictionary as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101069/c-sharp-dictionary-one-key-many-values

Comment: +1 for the dictionary approach (yup that's you, Emmad), makes the code more self-evident. But the code that you have is actually quite OK. I'd even argue that it's a heck of a lot safer than other "more elegant" solutions out there.

Comment: You can change the `foreach` to a `parents.Select...`: `parents.Select (p => new Parent
 {
  ParentName = p.ParentName,
  ChildNames = children.Where (c => c.ParentName == p.ParentName).Select (c => c.ChildName)
 });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) for best performance with a little memory penalty:

```
 var clu = children.ToLookup(x => x.ParentName, x => x.ChildName);
 parents.ForEach(p => p.ChildNames = clu[p.ParentName]);
```

Comment: +1. Ah I see now, yes I like this. Immutability purists will hate it, but the key here is not the Foreach method, but rather using the "ToLookup" to perform a succinct GroupJoin and I agree with the performance/memory tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extension method for enumerables:

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    if (action == null)
        return;
    foreach (T obj in source)
        action(obj);
}
```

And then do:

```
parents.Each(p => p.ChildNames = children.Where(c => c.ParentName == p.ParentName)
                                         .Select(c => c.ChildName));
```

Comment: I forgot that there is already a `ForEach` extension that I could use.  Thanks for the reminder. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a group join. LINQ isn't meant to update, though. So I'm not sure whether this would actually get you anywhere useful.

```
IEnumerable<Parent> parents = ...;

var parentsWithChildren = parents.GroupJoin(children,
                                            c => c.ParentName,
                                            c => c.ParentName,
                                            (a, b) => new
                                                      {
                                                          Parent = a,
                                                          ChildNames = b.Select(x => x.ChildName)
                                                      });

foreach (var v in parentsWithChildren)
{
    v.Parent.ChildNames = v.ChildNames;
}
```

This would certainly help if all you were given were parent *names* and children, rather than full `Parent` objects, since then you could just group join that collection to the child names, and create instances of parents where I create an anonymous type (`(a, b) => new { ... }`). But since I'm assuming your `Parent` objects would realistically hold more than just a name and that this is just an example, this seems like your best bet.

Comment: +1. Yeah, that was the only other option I could think of too. I have it included in my DotNetFiddle sample using alternate linqy syntax, but it's pretty much identical to your code (you're fast!). :)  If no-one else comes up with a better answer, I'll mark yours.

Answer (score 1):

Consider calling the name of a parent as `Parent.Name` instead of `Parent.ParentName`(a parent's parent?), `Child` has the same problem...

```
class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ChildrenNames { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can completely avoid `foreach` by creating `parentNames` array first:

```
var parentNames = new[] { "Lee", "Bob", "Tom" };
var allChildren = new List<Child>()
{
    new Child() {ParentName = "Lee", Name = "A"},
    new Child() {ParentName = "Tom", Name = "B"},
    new Child() {ParentName = "Tom", Name = "C"}
};
```

Such that the parents are constructed entirely by LINQ without any side-effects (no updates to any variables), and it should be very simple:

```
var parents =
    from parentName in parentNames
    join child in allChildren on parentName equals child.ParentName into children
    select new Parent { Name = parentName, ChildrenNames = children.Select(c => c.Name) };
```

Comment: +1. Thanks Ken. Your solution is called a Group Join, which is pretty much the only other option I could think of too. @MatthewHaugen came up with the same idea (using alternate syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Given that LINQ is based on functional principles, side effects are generally a big no-no (and also the reason for why there's no `foreach` method).

I therefore suggest the following solution:

```
var parents = new List<Parent>()
{
    new Parent() { ParentName = "Lee" },
    new Parent() { ParentName = "Bob" },
    new Parent() { ParentName = "Tom" }
};

var children = new List<Child>()
{
    new Child() { ParentName = "Lee", ChildName = "A" },
    new Child() { ParentName = "Tom", ChildName = "B" },
    new Child() { ParentName = "Tom", ChildName = "C" }
};

var parentsWithChildren = parents.Select(x => new Parent 
{ 
    ParentName = x.ParentName, 
    ChildNames = children
        .Where(c => c.ParentName == x.ParentName)
        .Select(c => c.ChildName) 
});

foreach (var parent in parentsWithChildren)
{
    var childNamesConcentrated = string.Join(",", parent.ChildNames);

    var childNames = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(childNamesConcentrated) 
        ? "(empty)" : childNamesConcentrated;

    Console.WriteLine("Parent = {0}, Children = {1}", parent.ParentName, childNames);
}
```

The solution above, do **not** modify the `Parent` objects of the collection `parents` by setting their `ChildNames`. Instead it creates a new set of `Parent`s with their respective ChildNames.

Comment: "also the reason why there is no `foreach` method" - I beg to differ. There's no `.ForEach` method at the `IEnumerable` level. But even then, if you PLINQ it, you can call `ForAll`.

Comment: @code4life, Please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: so you're saying that `myCollection.Select(x=>something(x)).ToList().AsParallel().ForAll(...)` doesn't exist?

Comment: @code4life, Not at all. `PLINQ` _needs_ to have the `ForAll` method, in order to iterate through the collection in parallel - which is an exception (note that I wrote `side effects are GENERALLY a big no-no`). The link I provided simply confirms what my answer says: That `LINQ` is build around functional principles, and therefore a `ForEach` method is not available - and shouldn't.

Comment: Immutability is a good design pattern and I appreciate your emphasis on it.