# How do I interpolate strings?

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

I want to do the following in C# (coming from a Python background):

```
strVar = "stack"
mystr  = "This is %soverflow" % (strVar)
```

How do I replace the token inside the string with the value outside of it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
string mystr = string.Format("This is {0}overflow", strVar);
```

And you could also use [named parameters](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/04/fun-with-named-formats-string-parsing-and-edge-cases.aspx) instead of indexes.

Answer (score 282):

This has been added as of C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015+).

**Example:**

```
var planetName = "Bob";
var myName = "Ford"; 
var formattedStr = $"Hello planet {planetName}, my name is {myName}!";
// formattedStr should be "Hello planet Bob, my name is Ford!"
```

**This is syntactic sugar for:**

```
var formattedStr = String.Format("Hello planet {0}, my name is {1}!", planetName, myName);
```

Additional Resources:

[String Interpolation for C# (v2) Discussion](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/570614)

[C# 6.0 Language Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

Comment: Patch for mono (dated 2009, your mileage may vary)
http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Dec-20.html

Comment: For the mono users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208869/c-sharp-6-0-string-interpolation-in-mono-mcs

Comment: This feature is such a beautiful thing.  Especially with VS2015 and the editor support so you can clearly see the interpolated strings and get intellisense.   It even works with methods!  `$("This feature is {GetDescription(FEATURE_AMAZING))}");`

Answer (score 14):

You can use `string.Format` to drop values into strings:

```
private static readonly string formatString = "This is {0}overflow";
...
var strVar = "stack";
var myStr = string.Format(formatString, "stack");
```

An alternative is to use the C# concatenation operator:

```
var strVar = "stack";
var myStr = "This is " + strVar + "overflow";
```

If you're doing a lot of concatenations use the `StringBuilder` class which is more efficient:

```
var strVar = "stack";
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("This is ");
for (;;)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(strVar); // spot the deliberate mistake ;-)
}
stringBuilder.Append("overflow");
var myStr = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 12):

If you currently use Visual Studio 2015 with C# 6.0, try the following:

```
var strVar = "stack";

string str = $"This is {strVar} OverFlow";
```

that feature is called string interpolation.

Answer (score 11):

C# 6.0

```
string mystr = $"This is {strVar}overflow";
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no operator for that. You need to use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

```
string strVar = "stack";
string mystr  = string.Format("This is {0}soverflow", strVar);
```

Unfortunately `string.Format` is a static method, so you can't simply write `"This is {0}soverflow".Format(strVar)`. Some people have defined an extension method, that allows this syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Use `string.Format`:

```
string mystr = string.Format("This is {0}overflow", "stack");
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `String.Format()`. The syntax is a bit different, numerical placeholders are used instead.

Example:

```
String.Format("item {0}, item {1}", "one", "two")
```

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options.  You can either use String.Format or you can use the concatenation operator.

```
String newString = String.Format("I inserted this string {0} into this one", oldstring);
```

OR

```
String newString = "I inserted this string " + oldstring + " into this one";
```

Comment: Under the covers `String.Format()` uses StringBuilder. StringBuilder is typically more efficient when concatenating a lot of strings but the concatenation operator is perfect for one offs. `String.Format()` is useful when formatting needs to be applied to the output, e.g. to add padding or leading zeros to numeric values. So using `String.Format()` in a loop will potentially instantiate a lot of StringBuilders. In that situation it is better to use a single StringBuilder declared outside the loop and `AppendFormat()` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
strVar = "stack"
mystr  = String.Format("This is {0}", strVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with Expansive: https://github.com/anderly/Expansive

Comment: C# has a built in interpolation mechanism. There's absolutely no reason to include a library for this functionality.

Comment: @Displayname look at the date on the question. C# didn't always have built-in string interpolation. It was added in C# 6 in 2016. Hence, the reason for my answer in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

There's one more way to implement placeholders with string.Replace, oddly helps in certain situations:

```
mystr = mystr.Replace("%soverflow", strVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way

> String interpolation

The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated string. e.g.

```
string name = "Mark";
string surname = "D'souza";
WriteLine($"Name :{name} Surname :{surname}" );//Name :Mark Surname :D'souza
```

An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain interpolated expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a result string, items with interpolated expressions are replaced by the string representations of the expression results.

> String.Format

Use String.Format if you need to insert the value of an object, variable, or expression into another string.E.g.

```
WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0}, Surname : {1}", name, surname));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now create an interpolated string not only with the $ sign, but also with €.

```
string name = "Michael";

string a = €"Hello, {name}!";
string b = $"Hello, {name}!";

Console.WriteLine(a == b); \/\/ True
```

The .NET XI version (.NET 11) also promises to introduce support for the £ symbol.

Reference: https://medium.com/@alexeynovikov_89393/all-new-c-13-features-whats-new-in-net-10-and-why-there-is-no-net-9-5ae756f84dc9

Answer (score -1):

**Basic example**:

```
        var name = "Vikas";
        Console.WriteLine($"My name is {name}");
```

**Adding Special characters**:

```
string name = "John";
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, \"are you {name}?\", but not the terminator movie one :-{{");
//output-Hello, "are you John?", but not the terminator movie one :-{
```

Not just replacing token with value, You can do a lot more with string interpolation in C#

**Evaluating Expression**

```
Console.WriteLine($"The greater one is: { Math.Max(10, 20) }");
//output - The greater one is: 20
```

**Method call**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The 5*5  is {MultipleByItSelf(5)}");
    }
  
    static int MultipleByItSelf(int num)
    {           
        return num * num;
    }
```

Source: [String Interpolation in C# with examples](https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/string-interpolation-in-c-with-examples/308)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the dollar sign and curl brackets.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}! Today is {date.DayOfWeek}, it's {date:HH:mm} now.");
```

See doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).