# C# ValueTuple properties naming

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, valuetuple

I'm trying ValueTuple Class in C#, and i have a doubt about properties naming, let's see:

If instantiate a ValueTuple declaring the object like this: `var tuple1 = (Name: "Name1", Age: 25);`
We can name the properties,

but, like this: `ValueTuple<string,int> tuple2 = (Name: "Name1", Age: 25);`

we get a warning that says the names are ignored,so

We should type: `ValueTuple<string,int> tuple2 = ("Name1",25);`

Then the properties will be `tuple2.Item1` and `tuple2.Item2`

Can someone explain this newbie  the reason about this?

Than you in advantage

Comment: `ValueTuple` is just a normal C# type with no special support from the compiler. It's members are always called `Item1`, `Item2` and so on. However, the `(x, y)` tuple syntax has special support from the compiler which introduces other names for the tuple members and maps them to the appropriate `ValueType` names in the generated IL code.

Comment: "but, like this: `ValueTuple<string,int> tuple2 = (Name: "Name1", Age: 25);`
we get an error" - no you don't; not on the code you've shown. You get warnings that the names in the tuple literal are effectively ignored, but you don't get an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name ValueTuple properties when creating with new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565738/name-valuetuple-properties-when-creating-with-new)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two different "kinds" of tuples involved here: the .NET `ValueTuple<...>` types, and C# tuple types. C# tuple types can have element names; `ValueTuple<...>` types can't. (There's simply nowhere in the type system for that to live in a normal way.)

At execution time, a value is only aware of its .NET type. For example, if you use:

```
(string x, int y) tuple1 = ("hello", 10);
(string a, int b) tuple2 = ("hello", 10);
DoSomethingWithValue(tuple1);
DoSomethingWithValue(tuple2);
...
void DoSomethingWithValue(object value) { ... }
```

then `DoSomethingWithValue` wouldn't be able to distinguish between the two tuple values at all. The information is only available at compile-time.

Information about element names for things like parameters and return types is propagated via attributes that the C# compiler consumes. So for example, a method declared like this:

```
public (string name, int score) GetFoo()
```

is compiled in IL as if it had been declared like this:

```
[TupleElementNames(new string[] { "name", "score" }]
public ValueTuple<string, int> GetFoo()
```

The C# language defines appropriate conversions between the .NET types and the C# tuple types to make it as seamless as possible.

In terms of how to use tuples, I'd use the C# tuple types as far as you can. Naming the tuple elements makes a huge difference in usability.

Comment: Thank you Jon, this helped me a lot to understand what is going on, and [this](http://josephwoodward.co.uk/2017/04/csharp-7-valuetuple-types-and-their-limitations) C# 7 paragraph helped too

Answer (score 3):

What you want to define is

```
(string Name,int Age) tuple1 = (Name: "Name1", Age: 25);
```

what you are defining is

```
ValueTuple<string,int> tuple2 = (Name: "Name1", Age: 25);
```

Look at the difference between in Type you are defining. Both are two different things if you take the name.

Comment: That does not answer the question at all - the underlying type is a `ValueTuple` in both cases (also the `var` example OP used is equivalent to your first example)

Comment: OP wants to know why they are different. That's what I have given here as both are different types.

Comment: They ARE NOT different types. Try your code and add `Console.WriteLine(tuple1.GetType().FullName);` and `Console.WriteLine(tuple2.GetType().FullName);`

Comment: They are different types at compile-time, but not at execution time. Just like `dynamic` and `object`.

Answer (score -1):

In short: No, you can't create ValueTuples with named fields like this.

In detail: Have a look at [Name ValueTuple properties when creating with new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565738/name-valuetuple-properties-when-creating-with-new) - your question is answered very well there.