# What does (datatype, datatype) x = (value, value) mean in C#? What is the actual data type of x?

Tags: c#, .net

I have come across this code -

```
(int, int) x = (10, 10);
```

What does it mean? What actually is `x`?

Comment: It's a [ValueTuple<int, int>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.7.2) and this is a shorthand way of doing `ValueTuple<int, int> x = new ValueTuple<int, int>(10, 10)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46602134/34092 may be worth a read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have there is a [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> A tuple is a data structure that has a specific number and sequence of elements. An example of a tuple is a data structure with three elements (known as a 3-tuple or triple) that is used to store an identifier such as a person's name in the first element, a year in the second element, and the person's income for that year in the third element.

They were introduced in C# 7.

Another way of writing it is like this:

```
ValueTuple<int, int> x = (10, 10);
```

or even:

```
ValueTuple<int, int> x = new ValueTuple<int, int>(10, 10);
```

You can access the values like so:

```
int val1 = x.Item1;
int val2 = x.Item2;
```

You can also alias them and then access the values by name:

```
(int A, int B) x = (10, 10); // or  var (A, B) = (10, 10);
int a = x.A;
int b = x.B;
```

You can read about how the ValueTuple aliases work over in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489034/3181933).