# Can you declare item names in a ValueTuple value in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, valuetuple

Is it possible to declare a ValueTuple as a value in a Dictionary, *and* include names for the items in the ValueTuple?

I've tried:

```
var x = new Dictionary<String, ValueTuple<name: String, id: String> = {...}
```

but I didn't really expect that to work, but then neither did this:

```
var x = new Dictionary<String, ValueTuple<String, String>> = {
  { "mary", (name: "foo", id: "green") }}
```

note that the previous declaration works without mentioning name and id, but then I can't then access the tuple members by name..

```
var x = new Dictionary<String, ValueTuple<String, String>> = {
  { "mary", ("foo", "green") }}

var y = x["mary"].foo   // won't work
```

Comment: You could do this `Dictionary<string, (string name, string id)>`

Comment: oh! So the compiler ascertains its a ValueTuple without me naming the type! I think that's the first time I've ever seen <> accepting anything other than an explicit type..

Comment: Non-default field names for `ValueTuple` values (i.e. the names you give the fields rather than `Item1`, `Item2`, etc.) are inferred by the compiler at compile-time, used only in the context in which they can be inferred, and are not actually part of the type itself and so cannot cross an inference boundary. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565738/name-valuetuple-properties-when-creating-with-new/43566072#43566072. If you want to access fields by name, then you need to stipulate the names when you use the values (e.g. via deconstruction syntax)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [named tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples) in the following way:

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<string, (string name, string id)>();
dict.Add("Mary", ("Foo", "green"));
...
var id = dict["Mary"].id; //get an Id value
```

This syntax is available starting from [C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples).

If you prefer a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers), you can declare a dictionary like

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<string, (string name, string id)>
{
    { "Mary", ("Foo", "green") }
};
```

This declaration `var y = x["mary"].foo` won't work, because `foo` is value of tuple item, not the name. To get a `foo` value you should use `dict["Mary"].name`

Comment: @MichaelRayLovett Does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

The names are only in the code, not in the data.

You can do this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, (string, string)>();
dict.Add("Mary", (name: "Foo", id: "green"));
(string foo, string bar) t1 = dict["Mary"];
var v1 = t1.foo; // Foo
var v2 = t1.bar; // green
```

While the tuple is added to the dictionary with **name** and **id** value names, it is retrieved with **foo** and **bar** value names.