# How to convert List of objects to Tuple of objects in c#

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a `List<object>` and I want to convert it to `Tuple<object, ..., object>`. How can I do it for *any* `Count` of `List` (which is guaranteed to be *short enough*)?

Comment: Note, that tuple can have *restricted*  number of fields (7 + 1 at most): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8?view=net-7.0

Comment: Yes I know but up to 8 will be enough

Comment: And how would you use such a tuple in your project, then?

Comment: "_Yes I know but up to 8 will be enough_" Then write a method that checks how many items are in the list and depending on the number of items create an instance of the appropriate Tuple type with the list elements passed to the Tuple constructor. (`if`or `switch`-`case` statements/expressions will enable you to do that...) It will not be the prettiest thing in the world, but it will do what you wish for (be always very, very cautious about what you wish for...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that unlike `List<T>`, tuple can have very limited numer of fields (`7 + 1` in .Net 7)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8?view=net-7.0

If the list is *short enough*, you can try to create tuple with a help of *reflection* (i.e. to call the required [Tuple.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple.create?view=net-7.0) method):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

...

// List<T>, not necessary List<Object>
List<int> data = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 7 };

...

var tuple = typeof(Tuple)
  .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
  .First(method => method.Name == "Create" && 
                   method.GetParameters().Length == data.Count)
  .MakeGenericMethod(Enumerable
     .Repeat(data.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0], data.Count)
     .ToArray())
  .Invoke(null, data.Select(item => (object) item).ToArray());

// Let's have a look:
Console.Write(tuple);
```

Output:

```
(4, 5, 7)
```

Note, that in such implementation, all fields of the tuple are of the *same* type (which is taken from list declaration). If you want to use *actual* item types change `MakeGenericMethod` call

```
   ...

   .MakeGenericMethod(data.Select(item => item?.GetType() ?? typeof(object))
      .ToArray())

   ...
```

Comment: I was going to post the same answer but I realized -- how do you use this? If you make this a method, how do you communicate the return type in a useful manner?

Comment: @BurnsBA: I treat the question as an pure *academic* one: when given a list return a tuple (a pretty good exercise for reflection - static overload methods with differrent generic parameters). Since we can get *any* of `Tuple<T1>`, `Tuple<T1, T2>`, ..., `Tuple<T1, T2, ..., Tn>` instances, hardly can we send these intances better than being cast to `object`...

Comment: Thank you! Could you please also tell me how can I create `TupleValue` from `Dictionary<srting, object>` and preserve `DataType`? So I would like to convert `new Dictionary<string, object>() { {"First": 1}, {"Second": "2"}}` to `(First: 1, Second: "2")`. I guess that again Reflection must be used because I do not know the length of dictioanry in advance.

Comment: @Mr.Price: You can create `ValueTuple` with a help of reflection, but you can't specify fields' names: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565738/name-valuetuple-properties-when-creating-with-new

Comment: ohh :( Is there any other method to create `ValueTuple` from `Dictionary`? Or in general, is it possible to write 8 functions (because we can have up to 8 values in `ValueTuple`) which enable me to pass my names of the values in ValueTuple? I mean a function `public static GetValueTuple(string name1, ..., string name8, object value1, ..., object value8)` which return `ValueTuple` with names name1,...,name8 and appropriate values?

Comment: @Mr.Pice, assuming you manage to create such a ValueToken with field names only defined during runtime - so, how are you going to _use_ such ValueTokens in your code, then? Clearly, you can't refer to the tuple fields directly by name in the source code, as the tuple field names would be unknown when you write and compile your project (they would only become known during runtime once somehow a ValueTuple would be created from some dictionary). TL;DR: What's the point of attempting this?