# C# 6.0 String Interpolation in Mono MCS

Tags: mono, c#-6.0

I'm using latest Mono 3.12.1. All of the C#6 features are working for me, apart from string interpolation. I'm using MCS compiler.

Here's my code:

```
const string someString = "Some String";
var str = $"string: {someString}";
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error CS1056: Unexpected character `$'
```

Is string interpolation supported by Mono?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a newer version of Mono for this, it will be part of the Mono 4.0 release, which has been branched, but has not been published yet.

So you will need to build it yourself for now

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Unfortunately building Mono from scratch is extremely hard (even with all the instructions), I've spent a couple of full days trying it to build without any success. DLL/Cygwin hell galore. I guess I'll have to wait for the official build then.

Comment: ... meanwhile published, Mono is currently at version 5.14