# reuse interpolated strings

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

Has anyone figured out how to reuse an interpolated string?

I.e. can anyone figure out how to do away with the `string.Format` in the following block of code?

```
foreach(var s in new[]{ "Primary_{0}_Home", "Secondary_{0}_Work" }){
    sql = $"SELECT {string.format(s, "Street")}, {string.format(s, "City")} ..."
}
```

Comment: it is not possible to do this. Reason: the interpolated values in the string are not necessarily in scope. Stick with `string.Format()` for this, it's a lot better!

Comment: use `string.Format` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354154/how-do-i-interpolate-strings

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that.

Interpolated strings are set on compile time. You can't use string interpolation to load a string to format something not directly in the scope.