# Passing a dynamic value to quantifier in C# regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a regex that I am trying to pass a variable to:

```
int i = 0;  
Match match = Regex.Match(strFile, "(^.{i})|(godness\\w+)(?<=\\2(\\d+).*?\\2)(\\d+)");
```

I'd like the regex engine to parse `{i}` as the number that the `i` variable holds.

The way I am doing that does not work as I get no matches when the text contains matching substrings.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need insert a variable inside a regex command

Comment: without use string interpolation

Comment: why don't you try concatenation?

Comment: not really  ,  please explain

Comment: i don't know much C# but you can try `"(^.{" + i + "})|(godness\\w+)(?<=\\2(\\d+).*?\\2)(\\d+)"`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354154/how-do-i-interpolate-strings) .

Comment: This is not a duplicate since the question is about the specific use of string iterpolation/string.Format when it comes to regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not clear what strings you want to match with your regex, but if you need to use a vriable in the pattern, you can easily use [*string interpolation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) inside a [*verbatim string literal*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string). Verbatim string literals are preferred when declaring regex patterns in order to avoid overescaping.

Since string interpolation was introduced in C#6.0 only, you can use `string.Format`:

```
string.Format(@"(^.{{{0}}})|(godness\w+)(?<=\2(\d+).*?\2)(\d+)", i)
```

Else, beginning with C#6.0, this seems a better alternative:

```
int i = 0;
Match match = Regex.Match(strFile, $@"(^.{{{i}}})|(godness\w+)(?<=\2(\d+).*?\2)(\d+)");
```

The regex pattern will look like

```
(^.{0})|(godness\w+)(?<=\2(\d+).*?\2)(\d+)
   ^^^
```

Comment: Using string interpolation can avoid changing index num for `string.Format()` But the drawback is you have to remember to un-escape `{{X}}` back to original valid regex value when you copy the regex string value to use at somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

You may try this Concept, where you may use i as parameter and put any value of i.

```
int i = 0;
 string Value =string.Format("(^.{0})|(godness\\w+)(?<=\\2(\\d+).*?\\2)(\\d+)",i);
 Match match = Regex.Match(strFile, Value);
```

Comment: I think the braces were meant to be part of the regex.  Since actual braces have to be escaped for `String.Format()`, it should be `{{{0}}}`.

Comment: Here all those thing is convert as string and where we had written " {0} " for passing parameter which replace with value of  " i ".