# Dynamic weblink C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a google translator link, that depends on my input. To make things clearer, here my "dynamic link":

```
private static string _GoogleLink = $"https://translate.google.com/?hl=de#{_SourceLanguage}/{_TargetLanguage}/{_SourceInput}"
```

I think it´s clear what i try to do, but the link doesn´t work this way, it just enters

```
https://translate.google.com/?hl=de#//
```

in my browser. I execute the link with this method:

```
public static void Translate(string input, string sourceLang, string targetLang)
{
    _SourceInput = input;
    _TargetLanguage = targetLang;
    _SourceLanguage = sourceLang;

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(_GoogleLink);
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code and checked whether the parameters contain the correct values? Also: From the code snippet you provided the use of a static field in the class seems not necessary.

Comment: static variables are evaluated in the static constructor, `_GoogleLink` does not get evaluated again in the Translate method.

Comment: The $ is just a shortcut to string formatting. The formatting doesn't happen anytime you change the values of _SourceInput etc... but only when you define the string _GoogleLink_ and this being a static string is defined before your code reaches the Translate method. Just move the _GoogleLink_ as local variable inside the _Translate_ method

Comment: Duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26977877/107625).

Comment: If your question got answerd pls accept it - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Your static field gets evaluated upon the static creation, it never gets "updated" with the correct values - use a property instead of an field, which gets evaluated every time the getter is called.

```
private static string _GoogleLink => $"https://translate.google.com/?hl=de#{_SourceLanguage}/{_TargetLanguage}/{_SourceInput}";
```

Or old School Syntax

```
private static string _GoogleLink { get { return $"https://translate.google.com/?hl=de#{_SourceLanguage}/{_TargetLanguage}/{_SourceInput}"; } }
```

But you should consider re-designing your method to this:

```
//instead of void - use string as a return
public static string Translate(string input, string sourceLang, string targetLang)
{
    //instead of saving your passed values, into static fields - transform the string right here and now and return it
    return $"https://translate.google.com/?hl=de#{sourceLang}/{targetLang}/{input}";
}
```

I believe this syntax is more understandable.