# C# 7 tuples and lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda, tuples, c#-7.0

With new c# 7 tuple syntax, is it possible to specify a lambda with a tuple as parameter and use unpacked values inside the lambda?

Example:

```
var list = new List<(int,int)>();
```

normal way to use a tuple in lambda:

```
list.Select(value => value.Item1*2 + value.Item2/2);
```

i expected some new sugar to avoid `.Item1` `.Item2`, like:

```
list.Select((x,y) => x*2 + y/2);
```

The last line does not work because it is treated as two parameters for lambda. I am not sure if there is a way to do it actually.

EDIT:

I tried double parentesis in lambda definition and it didn't work: `((x,y)) => ...`, and maybe it was stupid to try, but double parenthesis actually work here:

```
list.Add((1,2));
```

Also, my question is not quite about avoiding ugly default names `.Item .Item2`, it is about actual unpacking a tuple in lambda (and maybe why it's not implemented or not possible). If you came here for a solution to default names, read [Sergey Berezovskiy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43082087/1788106).

EDIT 2:

Just thought of a more general use case: is it possible (or why not) to "deconstruct" tuple passed to a method? Like this:

```
void Foo((int,int)(x,y)) { x+y; }
```

Instead of this:

```
void Foo((int x,int y) value) { value.x+value.y }
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As you have observed, for:

```
var list = new List<(int,int)>();
```

One would at least expect to be able to do the following:

```
list.Select((x,y) => x*2 + y/2);
```

But the C# 7 compiler doesn't (yet) support this. It is also reasonable to desire sugar that would allow the following:

```
void Foo(int x, int y) => ...

Foo(list[0]);
```

with the compiler converting `Foo(list[0]);` to `Foo(list[0].Item1, list[0].Item2);` automatically.

Neither of these is currently possible. However, the issue, [Proposal: Tuple deconstruction in lambda argument list](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/258), exists on the `dotnet/csharplang` repo on GitHub, requesting that the language team consider these features for a future version of C#. Please do add your voices to that thread if you too would like to see support for this.

Answer (score 49):

You should specify names of tuple properties (well, ValueTuple have fields) otherwise default names will be used, as you have seen:

```
var list = new List<(int x, int y)>();
```

Now tuple have nicely named fields which you can use

```
list.Select(t => t.x * 2 + t.y / 2)
```

Don't forget to add *System.ValueTuple* package from NuGet and keep in mind that ValueTuples are mutable structs.

---

Update: Deconstruction currently represented only as an assignment to existing variables (deconstructon-assignment) or to newly created local variables (deconstruction-declaration). Applicable function member selection algorithm is the same as before:

> Each argument in argument list corresponds to a parameter in the function member declaration as described in §7.5.1.1, and any parameter to which no argument corresponds is an optional parameter.

Tuple variable is a single argument. It cannot correspond to several parameters in the formal parameters list of the method.

Comment: good, but it's only renaming, values are still fields of single object passed to lambda. i was curious if there is a way to deconstruct it into multiple variables.

Comment: @Rast: to my knowledge, deconstruction of tuples works only in contexts where your declaration of the variables can include the assignment from the tuple. That would preclude a parameter list. Sergey's example seems quite clean; what is it about it that doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: @Peter Duniho it's only my curiosity. I thought that deconstruction or something like that may be useful in this case.

Comment: @Rast `Enumerable.Select` has a `Func<TSource, TResult>` delegate as parameter. It accepts single argument of TSource type and you cannot change that

Comment: @Rast: maybe, but not in a parameter list, where assignments of non-default values isn't permitted. You could instead do something like `list.Select(t => { (int x, int y) = t; return x * 2 + y / 2 });`, but at that point I think you're losing the conciseness of the tuple syntax over the alternative above.

Answer (score 18):

Deconstructions in C# 7.0 support three forms:

- deconstruction-declaration (like `(var x, var y) = e;`),
- deconstruction-assignment (like `(x, y) = e;`),
- and deconstruction-foreach (like `foreach(var(x, y) in e) ...`).

Other contexts were considered, but likely have decreasing utility and we couldn't complete them in the C# 7.0 timeframe. Deconstruction in a let clause (`let (x, y) = e ...`) and in lambdas seem good candidates for future expansion.

The latter is being discussed in https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/258

Do voice your feedback and interest there, as it will help champion proposals.

More details on what was included in C# 7.0 deconstruction in the [design doc](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/deconstruction.md).

Answer (score 13):

The problem you're running into is the inability of the compiler to infer the type in this expression:

```
list.Select(((int x, int y) t) => t.x * 2 + t.y / 2);
```

But since `(int, int)` and `(int x, int y)` are the same CLR type (`System.ValueType<int, int>`), if you specify the type parameters:

```
list.Select<(int x, int y), int>(t => t.x * 2 + t.y / 2);
```

It will work.