# Is there a way in c# to deconstruct a tuple and pass the values in one line?

Tags: c#, tuples

assume the following simple code:

```
public (string, string) GetTuple()
{
    return ( "a", "b" );
}

public string DoSomethingWithStrings(string str1, string str2) => 
    str1 + str2;

public void Example1( )
{
    var (a, b) = GetTuple();

    var r = DoSomethingWithStrings( a, b );

    //not working
    //var r = DoSomethingWithStrings( GetTuple() );
}
```

Is there some syntatic sugar, an extension method or something, to make the compiler understand the last commented code line?

Im using a Pipe extension method, so my goal is, instead of

```
public void Example2()
{
    var t =
        GetTuple()
        .Pipe(
            t =>
                DoSomethingWithStrings( t.Item1, t.Item2 )
        );
}
```

I want

```
public void Example3()
{
    var t =
        GetTuple()
        .Pipe(
            ( a, b ) =>
                DoSomethingWithStrings( a, b )
        );
}
```

My best take is:

```
public static TResult Pipe<TInput, TResult>(
    this TInput input,
    Func<TInput, TResult> pipeFunc 
) => 
    pipeFunc( input );

public static TResult Pipe<TInput1, TInput2, TResult>(
    this (TInput1, TInput2) input,
    Func<TInput1, TInput2, TResult> pipeFunc
) =>
    input
    .Pipe(
        t => pipeFunc( t.Item1, t.Item2 )
    );
```

Needless to say that this will get very messy, if I want to do this for all kinds of tuple item counts.

Comment: @possum The 96 upvotes on the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43082026/11683) disagree that it's an opinion based question or a request for code review. The OP also registered almost 8 years ago, so probably too late to welcome either.

Comment: for his and mine defense, I wasnt very active in this time span :)

Comment: @GSerg Before you assert that, consider the question was edited afterwards to remove the opinionated language.

Comment: @possum Are you referring to [the change](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78165736/revisions) of "an elegant way" to "a way"? I saw it in its "elegant" form and I didn't think it was material, nor do I think that after the change.

Comment: I'd perhaps just provide an overload of DoSomethingWithStrings that takes a `this (string,string)` tuple then you could call `GetTuple().DoSomethingWithStrings()`, but your form can be simplified to `GetTuple().Pipe(DoSomethingWithStrings);`, no?

Comment: @flackoverstow possible... Not sure, if this lowers the number of overall needed overloads... Biggest disadvantage in my opinion is that this overloads are all over the project and not in one place, the Extension class.

Comment: You mean adding an overload of DoSomething ? It won't reduce the numer of overloads, but Pipe would; that could be in an extension class that is just imported where needed. Does feel kinda like finding a workaround for something that is broken for another reason though. The problem is that you have some methods that return a tuple whose output needs feeding into methods that don't accept a tuple. Before tuples were a thing that would have been methods that returned a StringPair fed into methods that accepted a pair of strings, and those methods should perhaps be adjusted to accept a StringPair

Comment: So all in, my musing on it is if there isnt any real merit in keeping `MethodX(string,string)` that you will always only want to feed with the `(string,string)` output of MethodY, just bite the bullet and make X accept a tuple instead