# Can you name C# 7 Tuple items inline?

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0

By default, when using C# 7 tuples, the items will named like `Item1`, `Item2`, and so on.

I know you can [name tuple items being returned by a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40013994). But can you do the same inline code, such as in the following example?

```
foreach (var item in list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => (a, b)))
{
    // ...
}
```

In the body of the `foreach`, I would like to be able to access the tuple at the end (containing `a` and `b`) using something better than `Item1` and `Item2`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can, by deconstructing the tuple:

```
foreach (var (boo,foo) in list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => (a, b)))
{
    //...
    Console.WriteLine($"{boo} {foo}");
}
```

or

```
foreach (var item in list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => (a, b)))
{
    //...
    var (boo,foo)=item;
    Console.WriteLine($"{boo} {foo}");
}
```

Even if you named the fields when declaring the tuple, you'd need the deconstruction syntax to access them as variables:

```
foreach (var (boo,foo) in list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => (boo:a, foo:b)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{boo} {foo}");
}
```

If you want to access the fields by name without deconstructing the tuple, you'll have to name them when the tuple is created:

```
foreach (var item in list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => (boo:a, foo:b)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.boo} {item.foo}");
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, I have read various articles on C# 7 tuples and haven't seen the colon syntax documented anywhere.

Comment: @Gigi you probably did, in the "deconstruction" sections of these articles. *Any* type can be deconstructed this way, as long as it has a `Deconstruct` member or *extension* method. Tuples are a natural fit for this. You could create extension deconstruction methods for types that don't have them now, eg KeyValuePair just begs for `void Deconstruct<TK,TV>(this KeyValuePair,out TK key, out TV value) ...` method

Comment: Example usage of the new tuple syntax with `ref`, `out`, and `ref local` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46019408/147511)

Answer (score 3):

Note that C# 7.1 will add a refinement on tuple names. Not only can tuple elements be named explicitly (using the name-colon syntax), but their names can be inferred. This is similar to the inference of member names in anonymous types.

For instance, `var t = (a, this.b, y.c, d: 4); // t.a, t.b, t.c and t.d exist`

See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/infer-tuple-names.md for more details.