# How to create named reference-type tuples?

Tags: c#, tuples, named, reference-type, c#-7.0

The following line creates a named `ValueTuple`:

```
var tuple = (a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6);
```

Value types can not be passed around efficiently. Does `C# 7` offer a way to create named tuples of the `Tuple` type?

Comment: No, these are two different types

Comment: How do you intend to use these tuples? You can't claim efficiency on one over the other universally... it depends on how you use it.

Comment: Adding to what @JeffMercado said, consider that reference types incur a GC penalty, so depending on circumstances sometimes copying a value typed structure around is faster than causing a lot of GC pressure. One specific case where this happens is if you are creating and "forgetting" objects at a high frequency, such that the GC is constantly having to run because of allocation pressure. The performance penalty you pay in those cases can sometimes be worse than a series of value type copies. Only a profiler can tell you with certainty though.

Comment: @ ozeanix I understand the reasoning for ValueTuple - created often, used once - but most of the time you just want to use Tuples as simple containers with the convenience of the syntax, for example as a data package in class properties `public (int a, int b) Data;`

Comment: Then there's no use for you to be preferring `Tuple` over `ValueTuple` then. Use what the language provides for you first until you could determine that you could benefit from using `Tuple`. Judging by what you have shown here, you don't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean if there's a way to attach other names to the properties of `System.Tuple<...>` instances, no there isn't.

Depending on why you want it, you might get around it by converting `System.Tuple<...>` instances to `System.ValueTuple<...>` instances using the `ToValueTuple` overloads in [TupleExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.tupleextensions) and back using the `ToTuple` overloads.

If you don't really need the tuples, you can deconstruct them into discrete variables using the `Deconstruct` overloads or the `var (v1, .., vn) = tuple` deconstruction syntax.

Comment: Tuple has properties `Itemn`, named tuples are, well, named. It's not easy to implement

Comment: Yes, @Brandon, it would be easy to implement and it would have been easier to not introduce a new type for tuples. So it looks. But if you feel that way, chances are you're doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the problem is; everything works as expected for me for passing the new `ValueTuple<T>` with **out**, **ref**, and the new **ref locals**.

I'm using **.NET 4.7** and have my **C#7** compiler set to "latest" in the `.csproj` settings "Advanced..." button.

**Demonstration functions (and data):**

```
static (int, int) g = (1, 2);

static void SetValues(int a, int b, ref (int, int) tt) => tt = (a, b);

static void SetValuesOut(int a, int b, out (int, int) tt) => tt = (a, b);

static ref (int, int) GetKnownTuple() => ref g;

static ref (int, int) SelectRef(
    int ix, 
    ref (int, int) x, 
    ref (int, int) y, 
    ref (int, int) z)
{
    if (ix == 0) return ref x;
    if (ix == 1) return ref y;
    return ref z;
}
```

**Usage Examples:**

```
static void demo_usages() {

/// use 'ref return' to initialize a new 'ref local' tuple 'aa'
ref (int, int) aa = ref GetKnownTuple();

/// or use the same function without 'ref' to create a local COPY 'bb'
var bb = GetKnownTuple();

/// use 'ref' parameter to modify values of local copy 'bb' ('aa/g' are not altered)
SetValues(3, 4, ref bb);

/// deconstruction of 'ref local' tuple; reads values from referent 'g' (1, 2)
(int x, int y) = aa;

/// 'ref local' reference to a local tuple copy
ref (int, int) dd = ref bb;

/// use 'out' parameter to construct a new (non-'ref') local tuple 'cc'
SetValuesOut(y, x, out (int, int) cc);

/// ...or use 'out' with 'ref local' to wholly replace existing referent ('g' here)
SetValuesOut(5, 6, out aa);

/// 'ref return' function can also be used as assignment l-value...
GetKnownTuple() = (7, 8);

/// ('aa/g' are altered; locals 'bb' and 'cc' remain unchanged)

/// ...or assign a referent via 'ref local' variable (changes 'g' again)
aa = (9, 10);

/// conditional assignment via 'ref return'  (changes 'g' again)
SelectRef(0, ref aa, ref bb, ref cc) = (11, 12);

}
```

It should be clear that much more is possible, but all cannot be shown here since the OP's question does not get into too many specific further requirements.

Comment: this was very detailed and helpful explanation, thank you

Comment: You are not answering the question, that is just gibberish.