# How to return named tuples in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, get, set, tuples

I have a property that returns two items of type `DateTime`. When returning these values I have to reference them as `Item1` and `Item2`. How do I return with custom names e.g.

```
filter?.DateRanges.From
filter?.DateRanges.To
```

```
public Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> DateRanges
{
    get
    {
        From = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date.AddMonths(-1);
        To = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;

        if (Preset != 0)
        {
            if (Preset == DatePreset.SpecificRange)
            {
                From = From.Date;
                To = To.Date;
            }
            else
            {
                var dateRange = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).GetDateRangeByPreset(Preset);
                From = dateRange.From;
                To = dateRange.To;
            }
        }

        return new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(From, To);
    }
```

usage:

```
var from = filter?.DateRanges.Item1;
var to = filter?.DateRanges.Item2;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better naming in Tuple classes than "Item1", "Item2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745938/better-naming-in-tuple-classes-than-item1-item2)

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing as "named tuples". The alternative is to create a custom class with the property names you want

Comment: @RuiJarimba: There are definitely C# tuples with named elements, as of C# 7. They use `ValueTuple<>` rather than `Tuple<>` though.

Comment: Oh that's nice, I wasn't aware of that new feature. Thanks @DaisyShipton

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Like this:

```
public (DateTime Start, DateTime End) DateRanges
{
    get
    {
        return (DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This requires a recent version of C# and .Net.

Incidentally, watch out for this usage pattern:

```
var from = filter?.DateRanges.Start;
var to = filter?.DateRanges.End;
```

That's inefficient because it causes two identical tuples to be created.

This is better:

```
var range = filter?.DateRanges;

if (range.HasValue)
{
    var from  = range.Value.Start;
    var to    = range.Value.End;
}
```

However note that **tuples cannot be null** (they are value types) so you could write it like so:

```
if (filter != null)
{
    var range = filter.DateRanges;
    var from  = range.Start;
    var to    = range.End;
    ...
}
```

---

ADDENDUM (2022):

Nowadays you can much more simply assign the values of a tuple to local variables. Now we can rewrite the last example above like so:

```
if (filter != null)
{
    var (from, to) = filter.DateRanges;
    ...
}
```

Comment: strangely your second method does not work, var range = filter?.DateRanges; range variable doesn't allow Start and End

Comment: @KarimAli Ah, that's because it's a nullable (with the `?`) so I should have been using `.Value`. I've edited my answer. But actually it's pointless using a nullable here because tuples CANNOT be null.

Comment: This is not what was asked. Your answer is more than a syntax difference, it's a valuetype not reference which the Tuple<> syntax.

Comment: @JohnStock I pointed out that it's a value type in my answer where I said `(they are value types)`, so the fact that they are value types should be a surprise to no-one. I even bolded the part where I said `tuples cannot be null`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I appreciate you pointing out how the code can be misused (made less efficient) by calling the `DateRanges` method twice thereby creating 2 tuples. And furthermore providing a better "usage" recommendation. While the fact you are creating 2 tuples is somewhat obvious by inspection, it can be easily missed - especially when you are using code written by someone else!

Answer (score 3):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test t = new test();
        Console.WriteLine(t.NamedTuple.start);
        Console.WriteLine(t.NamedTuple.stop);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class test
{
    DateTime From;
    DateTime To;

    public (DateTime start, DateTime stop) NamedTuple
    {
        get
        {
            From = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date.AddMonths(-1);
            To = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;
            return (From, To);
        }

    }
}
```