# How to correctly use named tuples in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm currently working on a .NET core 2.1 project using C# 7+. I want to use a Named **Tuple** as the result of my method. Somehow I cannot manage to correctly create the method return parameters.

So far I have:

```
public static Tuple<List<Dictionary<string, object>>, List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>>> CreateFruits() 
{
   // logic to create apples and oranges

   return new Tuple<List<Dictionary<string, object>>, List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>>>(apples, oranges);
}
```

When I use my method Create Fruits I currently can use Apples and Oranges like that:

```
var result = MyHelper.CreateFruits();
var apples = result.Item1;
var oranges = result.Item2;
```

Instead of Item1 and Item2 I would like to use something like Apple and Orange.

```
var result = MyHelper.CreateFruits();
var apples = result.Apple;
var oranges = result.Orange;
```

Is it actually possible, I've read something about Named Tuples in C# 7, but I'm not so sure about how to use them correctly, especially with complex datatypes.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your code is *not* using the new tuples. It should be `(List<Dictionary<string, object>> apple, List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>> orange)`. This won't make this code easier to read and use though - why return suchs lists and dictionaries instead of strongly-typed objects?

Comment: From Rehman `Please check link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

I think you are missing refrence : (Apples: apple, Orange: orange)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745938/better-naming-in-tuple-classes-than-item1-item2

Comment: thanks! The datatypes are used to parse a not strongly typed message. I cannot change unfortunately.

Comment: Named tuples won't help. You should refactor return value type. I already feel the pain of developer, who will support this code. I doubt that even **you** will remember, what means `int` in the second `KVP` list after a couple of weeks.

Comment: @timhorton42 you *can* change this and return a `dynamic` type. You can use ExpandoObject or inherit from `DynamicObject`. Tuples are meant as a convenience feature for simple data objects and this is definitely not simple

Comment: @timhorton42 dynamic objects are essentially dictionaries with "magic" compiler support. You could think of a `dynamic` instance as a `Dictionary<string, object>` which would allow `apples` to become `dynamic[] apples` or `List<dynamic> apples`.

Comment: @Dennis, thanks btw. it's me supporting this 10 year old code, I try to make it better... of course it's kind of hard to refactor a class with more than 1000 lines and almost no methods.

Answer (score 3):

C# also supports the following, I think it suits what you are trying to do better

```
   class TuppleExample
{
    public (Apple, Orange) GetAppleAndOrage()
    {
        var apple = new Apple();
        var orange = new Orange();
        return (apple, orange);
    }

    public void EatAppleAndOrange()
    {
        var (apple, orange) = this.GetAppleAndOrage();

        apple.Bite();
        orange.PeelThenBite();
    }
}
class Apple { }
class Orange { }
```

The advantage being you skip the `.Item1`, `.Item2` syntax and access your tuple variables directly, just in the order they are declared.

Comment: That is a ValueTuple, otherwise known as a "named tuple", and it's only available in C#7+ / VS2017+. This is extremely important as not everyone can use this tooling