# What does GenericType<(param1, param2...)> means

Tags: c#, .net

I have been on [that link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188522/calculate-fingerprint-for-an-object) but there are some lines I really don't understand.

**1) List<()>**

```cs
    private readonly List<(string MemberName, Func<T, object> Fingerprint)> _fingerprints;
```

**2) For < Tproperty>**

```cs
    public FingerprintBuilder<T> For<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> memberExpression, Expression<Func<TProperty, TProperty>> fingerprint
```

How are they called? Can you provide some good links/explanations about them?

Comment: C# named tuple https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better naming in Tuple classes than "Item1", "Item2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745938/better-naming-in-tuple-classes-than-item1-item2)

Comment: It looks like the link is dictionary [or List<KeyValues(string,object)>] where the key is a string and the value is an object.  Your item 1 is a List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.  Your item 2 is enumerating through the values item 1.

Comment: Questions about tutorial or documentation are off-topic here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Where should I ask that kind of question?

Comment: @TanveerBadar Not really. However, I finally got what that basically means.

Answer (score 2):

When you see 
`Func<T, TProperty>` that is a delegate fingerprint, last item under <> is output, all others inputs.

So

```
Func<string, string, int> Fcn
```

Is a function that accepts 2 string parameters and returns integer value.

Lets define a function that accepts 2 strings and returns sum of their lengths

```
        Func<string, string, int> Fcn = (string s1, string s2) => s1.Length + s2.Length;

        var result = Fcn.Invoke("test", "test2");
        Console.WriteLine(result); // will return 9
```

In your case, it is just some generic types, but functionally it is the same like this example

Comment: This explains generic delegates. The question is about something else entirely.

Comment: Not entirely, but this answers the question only partially. OP seems to fail the entire basics behind generics, delegates are just one way to use generics.

Comment: @Djuro Thanks for the explanation concerning **Func<>** but what about the **For<TProperty>**? Can you?