# c# anonymous type declaration with parentheses

Tags: c#

[String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-interpolation)

in this example, there is a variable declaration that I haven't seen before and don't know what it is:

`var jh = (firstName: "Jupiter", lastName: "Hammon", born: 1711, published: 1761);`

there is [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) in C# but it uses curly braces.

the `jh.GetType()` returns

`System.ValueTuple 4[System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32]`

but `ValueTuple` generics are not key-value pairs. they have some items. this syntax is more like a dictionary of named fields.

so my question is what is this syntax called? I'm looking for Microsoft docs page for getting documentation and details about this syntax.

Comment: It's a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), the type tells you that which you could have googled.

Comment: It's good that you're reading and citing documentation but you should use that same resource to learn just what that `System.ValueTuple` is.

Comment: You are asking 3 questions here.  1) what this code does? 2) what this technic is called? 3) how to replace var with an explicit type?  For #1 and #2, see [Better naming in Tuple classes than “Item1”, “Item2”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40013994/3744182) and [What's the difference between System.ValueTuple and System.Tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41084411/3744182).  For #3 you need to clarify what you want for an "explicit type".  Do you mean some type you have created, that you want to construct using this syntax?  Or do you just want to know what type actually got created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned, this is `ValueTuple`. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084411/whats-the-difference-between-system-valuetuple-and-system-tuple)  for some description and comparison with a "ordinal" `Tuple`s. The official documentation also available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0).

The code you showed is the  just a typical declaration of such a ValueTuple. The syntax was  introduced in C# 7.0.

To replace `var`, you can use the following:

```
(string firstName, string lastName, int born, int published) jh = (firstName: "Jupiter", lastName: "Hammon", born: 1711, published: 1761);
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `(string firstName, string lastName, int born, int published) jh = (firs....` and `System.ValueTuple<string,string,int,int> jh = (firstName: "Jupiter", lastName: "Hammon", born: 1711, published: 1761);` ?

Comment: The main advantage is that with `(string firstName,...) jh=` syntax you will get tuple with named fields, so you will be able to reference the members as `jh.firstName`. If you declare as `ValueTuple<string,..> jh`, you will only able to use default names like `jh.Item1`. And yes, internally, the both records are absolutely identical - compiler will replace both with `ValueTuple<string, ...>` syntax.

Comment: Note that names are optional and that placing the names on both sides is not necessary.

Comment: as @DavidG mentioned, This is `Tuple type` which requires the `System.ValueTuple` as in [Tuple types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) says.