# What does this Method return? (C#)

Tags: c#, methods, task

Not so long ago I moved from Java to C# and I'm still learning and today I bumped into this in some code.

```
public async Task<(decimal Price, string NativeCurrency)> GetCurrentStockPrice(string ticker)
```

I'm wondering just based on the method signature what exactly does this method return? Does it return two values?

Comment: A [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) that is wrapped in a [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# anonymous type declaration with parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647070/c-sharp-anonymous-type-declaration-with-parentheses)

Comment: u can just return a tuple like that in c# not as a dictionary or HashSet

Answer (score 3):

This returns a tuple of `(decimal Price, string NativeCurrency)`

So you would call

```
var currentStockPrice = await GetCurrentStockPrice("USD") //or whatever the ticket string needs to be instead of "USD"
```

and

```
currentStockPrice.Item1 is decimal Price
currentStockPrice.Item2 is string NativeCurrency
```