# I need to create a dictionary where each key can map to several values

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

Im trying to figure out how I can create something similar to a dictionary, but where each key can map to several values.

Basically what I need is to be able to assign multiple values to the same key without knowing in advance how many values each key will correspond to. I also need to be able to add values to an existing key on multiple occasions. It would also be nice if I could detect when a key + value combination already exists.

An example of how the program should work:

```
list.Add(1,5);
list.Add(3,6);
list.Add(1,7);
list.Add(5,4);
list.Add(1,2);
list.Add(1,5);
```

This should ideally produce a table like this:

1: 5, 7, 2

3: 6

5: 4

Is there any existing construction in C# that I can use for this or do I have to implement my own class? Implementing the class would probably not be a big problem, but Im a bit short on time so it would be nice if I could use something that already exists.

Comment: Sounds like a regular dictionary, where the keys are strings or numbers and the values are lists. :) Except for the .Add(), where you'd have to add something to the *value* (i.e. the list) instead of the dictionary itself. Either way, it's good that your unit test is already written in the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick Solution**

As you have already mentioned, a Dictionary would be the best type to use. You can specify both the key type and value type to meet your needs, in your case you want an `int` key and a `List<int>` value.

This is easy enough to create:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

The challenge then comes with how you add records, you cannot simply do `Add(key, value)` because that will cause conflict which duplicate keys. So you have to first retrieve the list (if it exists) and add to that:

```
List<int> list = null;
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    list = dictionary[key];
}
else
{
    list = new List<int>();
    dictionary.Add(key, list);
}
list.Add(newValue);
```

---

**Preferred Solution**

This is obviously a few too many lines to use each time you want to add an item, so you would want to throw that into a helper function, or my preference would be to create your own class that extends the functionality of Dictionary. Something like this:

```
class ListDictionary<T1, T2> : Dictionary<T1, List<T2>>
{
    public void Add(T1 key, T2 value)
    {
        if (this.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            this[key].Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            List<T2> list = new List<T2>() { value };
            this.Add(key, list);
        }
    }

    public List<T2> GetValues(T1 key)
    {
        if(this.ContainsKey(key))
            return this[key];
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which you can then use as easy as you originally wanted:

```
ListDictionary<int, int> myDictionary = new ListDictionary<int, int>();

myDictionary.Add(1,5);
myDictionary.Add(3,6);
//...and so on
```

Then to get the list of values for your desired key:

```
List<int> keyValues = myDictionary.GetValues(key);
//check if NULL before using, NULL means the key does not exist
//alternatively you can check if the key exists with if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I ended up using HashSet<int> instead of List<int> and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `TKey` would be `int` and `TValue` would be `List<int>`, You can add as many element in List as it grow autmatically.

```
Dictionary <int, List<int>> dic = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

The way you can access the value would change, you can for instance add element in dictionary like

```
void AddToYourCustomDictionary(int key, int someValue)
{
   if(!dic.ContainsKey(key))
   {
      dic.Add(key, new List<int>());
       dic[key].Add(someValue);
   }
   else  
     dic[key].Add(someValue); //Adding element in existing key Value pair
}
```

To access element in Dictionary Key -> value i.e list,

```
Console.WriteLine(dic[key][indexOfList]);
```

Comment: And then you need some additional logic (overrid/replace Add)

Comment: `dic[key]` will throw an error if the key does not exist, so you cannot check if it is null like that

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of Lists quite easily e.g.

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>()
```

An Alternative if you have created a list of items and want to separate them into groups with different keys, which serves much the same purpose is the [Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403493/what-is-the-point-of-lookuptkey-telement) class.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

public void AddIfNotExistInDic(int key, int Value) {
    List<int> list = null;
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
        list = dictionary[key];
    }
    else {
        list = new List<int>();
        dictionary.Add(key, list);
    }

    if (!list.Contains(Value)) {
        list.Add(Value);
    }
}
```