# Dictionary with list as value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

A month ago we've started group project in college. Our topic is decision tree and my job in this iteration is to create a data collection. I used `Dictionary` with string as key and string as value. Today my team mate suggested me to use `List`as a collection of values. Does it make sense to keep using dictionary with string as key and list as value?

Can I easily modify values if they are in list in dictionary?

Thanks.

Comment: Make a try and come back if you got stuck, you can use `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: yes its easily modify let me know in case you need examples

Comment: "does it make sense to keep using dictionary with string as key and list as value" - well it's certainly *valid*. Whether or not it's the right thing to do in your situation is another matter, but we can't really tell that without more information.

Comment: See also the [Lookup class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403493/what-is-the-point-of-lookuptkey-telement), which is essentially a `Dictionary<TKey,List<TValue>>`.

Comment: Hi, I will recommend reading [Ask] and [Mcve]. For now your question is not really a question. We have no idea of the context, or the manipulation you wan't to do. And "easily" is a complexe word, everything is relativly easy when you know how to do it. I will recommend choosing a simple Bogus decision three. Hard code into a dictionnary. Sumarize in sentence what are the operation your need using the Bogus expression tree. Scpecifing that the datastructure is open an can be modify in order to have easier operation.

Comment: Well, i've just contacted with mate who gave me that idea, i didnt understand his idea, now he has explained me what he meant. I've to make List of Dictionaries i think, cuz the structure has to look like this http://prntscr.com/n4l9f3. We have Attribute class which cointains string as name of attribute and list with possible values and Attribute Structure class as a list of attributes. So the value on my prntscr is one of possible from attribute list.

Comment: Looks like you need a pivot table like in excel.

Comment: Is it collection? Never heard about it, im new to c#, we chose this language to learn something but now we regret it rofl

Comment: Sounds like an in-memory version of Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV). Appropriate only in rare circumstances, IMO.