# How can I combine data from rows in a list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that contains two properties, Sequence and Term.

```
termData <int,string>
```

For each Sequence there can be multiple Terms.

Is there a way that I can combine the terms for each Sequence number such that it creates another list looking something like:

1438690    "weather; the elements; fair weather

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want `<int, List<T>>`?

Comment: I am not sure about the expected output.

Comment: `.GroupBy(...)` / `group by ...`?

Comment: can you share the input and expected output, you cant have a list that is composed of <int, string>, it's either <int> or <string> not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a series of items with a single key referencing multiple items, you can use a [Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403493/what-is-the-point-of-lookuptkey-telement) object:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup( item => item.Sequence, item => item.Terms);
```

This code tells c# to create a lookup, which is just like a dictionary where `item.Sequence` is the key and `item.Terms` is the value. The value itself is a list which can be enumerated:

```
foreach (var item in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sequence {0} has these terms: {1}", item.Key, string.Join(",", item));
}
```

Output:

```
Sequence 1438690 has these terms: weather,the elements
Sequence 9672410 has these terms: dogs,cats
```

See my working example on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iUdj81)

Answer (score 3):

```
var _result = termData.GroupBy(x => x.Sequence)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    seq = x.Key,
                    term = x.Select(y => y.Term).ToList()
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new List<termData>();
list.Add(new termData() { Sequence = 1438690, Terms = "weather" });
list.Add(new termData() { Sequence = 1438690, Terms = "the elements" });
list.Add(new termData() { Sequence = 9672410, Terms = "dogs" });
list.Add(new termData() { Sequence = 9672410, Terms = "cats" });

var result = list
    .GroupBy(t => t.Sequence, t => t.Terms)
    .Select(g => g.Key + ";" + String.Join(";", g));
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

```
1438690;weather;the elements
9672410;dogs;cats
```