# More efficient way to search Lists of custom Classes

Tags: c#

I have this block of code that loops over a list containing a custom class, searching for a specific match and then sets some variables.

```
//"seq_obj" comes from somewhere else.
Sequencer_Object _s = new Sequencer_Object() {
    obj_name = seq_obj["obj_name"],
    trait_type = seq_obj["trait_type"],
    data_points = seq_obj["data_points"],
    param_path = seq_obj["param_path"]
)};


foreach (Object_Params _obj in _objects) {
    for (int x = 0; x < _obj.param_path.Count; x++) {
        //if found, set the friendly names
        if (_obj.param_path[x] == _s.param_path && _obj.obj_name[x] == _s.obj_name) {
            _s.friendly_param = _obj.param_displayname[x];
            _s.friendly_type = _obj.category;
            goto endsearch;
        }
    }
}
endsearch:
```

`_objects` above is a List<> of `Object_Params`, which itself contains lists. So I'm searching through lists of lists until it matches 2 values, and then copies over the other information it finds.

My custom classes look like this:

```
public class Object_Params
{
    public string category { get; set; }
    public List<string> obj_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> param_displayname { get; set; }
    public List<string> param_path { get; set; }
    public List<string> trait_type { get; set; }
}
```

each Category contains specific sets of parameters, traits, and other data. That's why `_objects` is a List, to contain each category.

```
public class Sequencer_Object
{
    public string obj_name { get; set; }
    public string param_path { get; set; }
    public string trait_type { get; set; }
    public dynamic data_points { get; set; }
    public string friendly_type { get; set; }
    public string friendly_param { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this sort of search? Since the `goto` only breaks out of the loop once the match is found, the `foreach` and `for` loops could potentially iterate through all items in the `_objects` List before it gets to the index that has the match.

Comment: I'd use LINQ: `var match = _objects.SelectMany(obj => obj.param_path).FirstOrDefault(...)`. But before any of that, I'd start following .NET naming conventions...

Comment: if the list is unsorted, and you only need to do this once, then a linear search is the best you can do. There might be only one match, and this could be at any index, so you might need to check each item. If you redo the operation many times you may start to benefit from sorting+binary search, search indices etc.

Comment: `goto endsearch;` ... Oo

Comment: Don't use parallel lists.  Make a class to represent all of the values and have one list of that one type, rather than separate lists for each of the logical properties.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am confused by your answer. All that bit does is return the very first param_path in the entire thing, doesn't really search for anything. I'm not quite versed in LINQ, so I'm not sure how to expand that into something useful.

Comment: @Servy Can you expand on what you mean? Are you saying to put each of the List<string> into its own class?

Comment: Whoops, yes, you're right - it doesn't find the first main item. But it's definitely feasible to do in LINQ. It would be more like `var match = _objects.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.param_path.Any(pp => ...));`. I would strongly suggest learning more about LINQ though - it's very, very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put them in a [lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403493/what-is-the-point-of-lookuptkey-telement):

```
var lookup = _objects
    .SelectMany
    (
        x => x.param_path.Select(y => new { Instance = x, Path = y })
    )
    .ToLookup
    (
        x => x.Path,
        y => y.Instance
    );
```

This essentially gives you a dictionary where the key is the param path and the item is a list of every instance that matches.

To find an instance that matches a particular path and display name, use:

```
var instances = lookup[pathToFind]
    .Where
    (
        x => x.param_displayname.Any( y => y == displayNameToFind )
    );
```

or, depending on your exact requirement:

```
var instances = lookup[pathToFind]
    .Where
    (
        x => x.param_displayname.Zip(x.param_path)
             .Any( x => x.Item1 == displayNameToFind && x.Item2 == pathToFind ) 
    );
```

This uses a hash table search which is more efficient (usually) than an overall table scan.

Comment: `x.param_displayname == displayNameToFind` doesn't quite work, since `param_displayname` (or really any other of the variables) are all lists, and the comparison breaks since it's List<string> == string.